# How does WCF create/read SOAP Messages

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I know that WCF is a framework used to build Web Services, and that when a service is run a WSDL is automatically generated.

I also know that BasicHttpBinding allows the Web Service to expect SOAP Messages to be transferred to and from it's endpoint.

How does WCF handle the sending/receiving of SOAP Messages? What does the Framework do to build these SOAP Messages and to Map the Message Body to the Service Operations (given in the WSDL)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binding is a collection of binding elements. WCF comes with a few bindings out-of-the-box, such as the BasicHttpBinding, created from a few selected binding elements.

The BasicHttpBinding uses an encoding element (specifically the [`TextMessageEncodingBindingElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement(v=vs.110).aspx)) that (de)serialize your object to and from a SOAP message.